# Syntax highlighting for trait keyword

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I noticed when [answering a PHP-releated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638226/retrieve-all-morphedby-relations/31651105#answer-31651105) that the `trait` keyword isn’t highlighted by the syntax highlighter, whilst other keywords such as `class`, `function`, and `interface` are.

Is it possible to have `trait` highlighted in the same way?

Comment: You'll need to ask the Google Prettify project to add the keyword, see the linked FAQ.